# Передать event через @click в Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, события

У меня не получается передать `event` в `@click`.

Вот такой пример:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary save-btn fs-5" type="submit" @click="saveChanges(e, table)">
    Сохранить
</button>
```

При `console.log(e)` выдает `undefined`, а при `e.preventDefault();` выдает ошибку `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault')`, вот сама функция:

```
saveChanges(e, table) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Буду благодарен за ответ.

Comment: event == событие) тоесть в чем собственно трудность?) `@click="saveChanges(e, table)` это собствественно что такое?) попробуйте так `@click="saveChanges(this, table)"` и **table** в данном случае вообще что такое?) предположу что `undefined`

Comment: table - это просто объект с данными. в принципе я указал что мне нужно передать событие, а не весь объект с data. мне уже помогли, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary save-btn fs-5" type="submit" @click="saveChanges($event, table)">
    Сохранить
</button>
```

В этом случае $event будет автоматически связан с текущим событием, происходящим при клике на кнопку. В функции saveChanges вы можете обращаться к событию через аргумент $event:

```
saveChanges(event, table) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    // Другие действия события
}
```

Теперь вы можете использовать $event для доступа к событию и выполнения операций с ним.